# Kotlin - Class secondary constructor with different parameter

Tags: android, constructor, kotlin

Whilst converting a rather simple application from Java to `Kotlin` I came across one 'problem' I can't seem to fix.

I have a class `ScanInfo` that looks like this in Java (without getters and setters)

```
public class ScanInfo {
    private String source;
    private String label_type;
    private String data;

    public ScanInfo(Intent intent) {
        ... Get Info from intent and assign the values ...
        this.source = ...
        this.label_type = ....
        this.data = ....
    }
}
```

Now in `Kotlin` i can create the class

```
class ScanInfo (var source: String, var label_type: String, var data: String)
```

But I have no idea how to get it to work so I can create a `ScanInfo` object with Intent as parameter. 
I tried with companion, object, companion object but I can't seem to find the right syntax.

Am I wrong to look for such a solution while using `Kotlin` or am I just not using the right `kotlin-constructor`?
If it's possible, how can I create a `ScanInfo` object with an Intent as parameter?

```
var result = ScanInfo(intent)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way:

```
class ScanInfo(intent: Intent) {
    private val source = intent.source
    private val labelType = intent.labelType
    private val data = intent.data
}
```

**OR**

```
class ScanInfo(intent: Intent) {
    private val source: String
    private val labelType: String
    private val data: String

    init {
        source = intent.data
        labelType = intent.data
        data = intent.data
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to add getters/setters too or change the visibility

Comment: Not sure if OP needs getters/setters for his class, but yes, you're right.

Comment: using the `init` method is the best choice

Comment: I've use the second option because I had more actions to be completed before getting the source/label_type/data information.
By removing the private indication of the declaration and changing them to var's, I have my needed solution.
Thank you!